# InvocableVariable Amount field not visible in Process Builder

Tags: apex, process-builder

Using Amount field in a webhook

I've created an Apex class webhook to post from Salesforce to Slack. I have tried with `Opportunity.Amount` field is defined as a Double or Decimal.

```
   @InvocableVariable(label='Amount')
   public Double amount;
```

I use the Apex class in a Process Builder, however when setting the Apex variables, and choosing the Amount field, under Field Reference, the Amount field is not available.

Do I need to declare the Amount field in the APEX in a different way?

**BELOW is the APEX**

public with sharing class SlackInvoiceRequestPublisher {

```
private static final String slackURL = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXX';

public class InvReqForm {
    @InvocableVariable(label='Account Name')
    public String accountName;
    @InvocableVariable(label='Amount')
    public Decimal amount;
}

@InvocableMethod(label='Post to Slack Invoice Request Forms')
public static void postToInvoiceRequest(List<InvReqForm> formfields) {
    InvReqForm o = formfields[0]; // If bulk, only post first to avoid overloading Slack channel
    Map<String,Object> msg = new Map<String,Object>();
    msg.put('text', 'Invoice Request Submitted:\n' 
            + '\n Account Name: ' + o.accountName 
            + '\n Total Contract Value: '+ o.amount 

    msg.put('mrkdwn', true);
    String body = JSON.serialize(msg);    
    System.enqueueJob(new QueueableSlackCall(slackURL, 'POST', body));
}

public class QueueableSlackCall implements System.Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {

    private final String url;
    private final String method;
    private final String body;

    public QueueableSlackCall(String url, String method, String body) {
        this.url = url;
        this.method = method;
        this.body = body;
    }

    public void execute(System.QueueableContext ctx) {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setMethod(method);
        req.setBody(body);
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: @kristin, make sure you are compliant with the [InvocableVariable Considerations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableVariable.htm)

Comment: @phil - as far as I know I am compliant. I changed the type to Decimal, but that didn't make a difference.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @phil - the code you pasted above is inside an inner class "container", right?

Comment: ...or, more importantly, your invocable method is taking a list as a parameter, right?

Comment: I think the answer to the question is "yes". I am a lowly Salesforce Admin, getting assistance from a developer on our engineering team, so am not totally sure of terminology. I updated the question above with the Apex class.

Is it possible you just can't reference a currency field in an invocable variable? The workaround is to create a formula field that returns a number and reference the currency field.

Comment: Additional thoughts -
I think there is a mis-match between Apex and Process Builder regarding the data type. The Apex is declaring Amount as decimal or double, but Salesforce has it coded as currency. We are not able to use currency as a data type in the Apex class.

The work around was to create a custom formula field, type of number, that points to the Amount field.

Answer (score 0):

Another work-around for this limitation is to use a formula to set the value to a Currency reference. See screenshot

[image: Example]